# TypeError: fn.bind is not a function with Discord.js Guild Member Update Event

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make logs for The `GuildMemberUpdate` event but whenever I run the code I keep getting. The error is here, I also provided the code within the event. I have updated my node and npm version to the latest but still the same error. I updated my package.json and package-lock.json file aswell but it still give the same error.

```
TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 12, `find` take a function.

Change

```js
newMember.roles.cache.find('id', value.id)
```

to

```js
newMember.roles.cache.find(value => value.id == "id")
```

Comment: I had figured it out now and yes thats correct thank you